# Set value to label(s) in table view with NotificationCenter

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a table view with a custom cell. In the cell I have a label that counts button presses in that specific cell.

The counter is part of a separate class:

```
class List {
    var name = ""
    var description = ""
    var counter: Int = 0

    init(name: String, description: String) {

        self.name = name
        self. description = description    
    } 
}         

var staticList: [List] =
        [ //Lots of names and descriptions.   
        ]
```

In viewDidLoad, I do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshLbl), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
```

And the function I have tried:

```
 @objc func refreshLbl(cell: MenuCell)
    {
        let indexPath = menuTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
       staticList[(indexPath?.row)!].counter = 0   
    } 
}
```

So, my goal here is to set the counter to 0 in all counterLabels when `func refreshLbl` is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply run this loop and update the value for counter to zero :

```
 for list in staticList{
        list.counter = 0
    }
```

and then reload table view : `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!